# Variable byte encoding - Information Retrieval

Tags: encoding, byte, computer-science, bit, information-retrieval

**Question:**

What is the largest gap that can be encoded in 2 bytes using the variable-
byte encoding ?

**Answer:**

With 2 bytes, we use 2 continuation bits, and 14 bits are available for gap encoding (2^0 to 2^13). Hence, the largest gap that can be encoded is 2^14 − 1 = 16383 (when all 14 bits are set to 1).

**I need to do the same question as above but for 3 bytes. Below is my answer but I am not sure if it is correct. Could somebody let me know if I am doing it correctly? thanks**

**Question:**

What is the largest gap that can be encoded in 3 bytes using the variable-
byte encoding ?

**My Answer:**

With 3 bytes, we use 3 continuation bits, and 21 bits are available for gap encoding (2^0 to 2^20). Hence, the largest gap that can be encoded is 2^21 − 1 = 2097151 (when all 21 bits are set to 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 3 bytes, we can use 3 continuation bits, and 21 bits are available for gap encoding (2^0 to 2^20). Hence, the largest gap that can be encoded is (2^21)-1 = 2097151 (when all 21 bits are set to 1).